# spring batch 3.0.6 not compatible with Spring core 4.2.4

Tags: java, spring

We recently started to implement batch process in our application using spring batch.
The spring-core that we are currently using is 4.2.4 However, the spring-batch 3.0.6 uses spring-core 4.0.5. 
I wanted to know does spring-batch 3.0.6 works with spring-core 4.2.4?

Comment: The problem was solved with spring-batch 3.0.7